# How to automate client server testing

Tags: python, server, automation, client

Im working on a project where I built a python socket server and client. When I run both the scrips simultaneously they work as expected. But I’m writing a test script which needs to eventually be automated. I have gotten the client to run within the test script but I am struggling with how to get the server to do the same. Im not really sure where to start with getting the server to run from my test script as I’ve never worked with anything like this before.